# Parallel distinct word count in Go

Tags: language-agnostic, parallel-processing, go, word-count

Jakob Østergaard [presented](http://unthought.net/c++/c_vs_c++.html) this challenge:

> Write a program that reads text from standard-input, and returns (prints) the total number of distinct words found in the text.

How can we meet this challenge with parallel programming (preferably in Go, but a description in English will suffice)?

Comment: Why do you think this problem is amenable to effective parallelization?

Comment: It seems unlikely that parallelizing this will be useful. You need a single process to split the text into tokens, which is a sizable chunk of the work, and the remaining task is to increment counts in a dictionary, which either requires locking, or keeping a separate dictionary per worker and merging them, likely eliminating any benefit you got from counting them separately.

Comment: Tim Bray created a parallel benchmark for processing log files, in a number of languages, called the ["Wide Finder"](http://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/200x/2008/05/01/Wide-Finder-2). You might find it relevant.  Processing files is something that can be done in parallel, but perhaps not the standard input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several possibilities, but I guess you mean "efficiently" ?

The general idea would be to split the text into manageable chunks, pile those chunks into a queue, and have multiple consumers handle the chunks.

This looks like a typical Map/Reduce application to me:

```
          _ Worker_
         /          \
        /            \
Splitter--- Worker ---Aggregator
        \            /
         \_ Worker _/
```

Ideally the "multiple" queues would be a single one with multiple consumers, so that if one worker slows down the whole process does not slows as much.

I would also use a signal from the Splitter to the Workers to let them know the input has been fully consumed and they can start send their results to the Aggregator.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution, in Go, to [Jakob Østergaard's problem](http://unthought.net/c++/c_vs_c++.html).

```
/*
    The problem: Write a program that reads text from 
    standard-input, and returns (prints) the total 
    number of distinct words found in the text. 

    C versus C++, Jakob Østergaard, February 24th, 2004
    http://unthought.net/c++/c_vs_c++.html
*/

package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "unicode"
)

func main() {
    rdr := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    words := make(map[string]bool, 1024*1024)
    word := make([]int, 0, 256)
    for {
        r, n, _ := rdr.ReadRune()
        if unicode.IsSpace(r) || n == 0 {
            if len(word) > 0 {
                words[string(word)] = true
                word = word[:0]
            }
            if n == 0 {
                break
            }
        } else {
            word = append(word, r)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(len(words))
}
```

It's naive to add the phrase "parallel programming" to this and most other problems and expect some magical improvement. Reading input sequentially from a stream and performing trivial computation provides no significant opportunities for [parallel computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_computing).

Comment: (-1) Reading from stdin is just a simplication, the real question is about the algoritmic work of doing count-distrinct in parallel which has real applications and real efficencies in parallel computing